# Configuring USART to send a character in ARM thumb assembly

Tags: stm32, gpio, usart, thumb

I am trying to send a character using my stm32. I am using Real Term serial capture program and have set up a baud rate of 9600.

I have attempted to write the initialization for the USART and GPIOA. So far, when I reset my device, it sends a NULL character to the serial capture program, so I think I am on the right track atleast. But I have tried writing a character to the USART_DR and have had no luck seeing the character at the serial capture side.

I have been following this link as a guide (http://www.micromouseonline.com/2009/12/31/stm32-usart-basics)

And here's a little guide for GPIO registers

```
@; GPIOx
@; MODER [15:0] 
@;0:'00'-> input mode, which allows the GPIO pin to be used as an input pin,
@;1:'01'-> Output mode, which allows the GPIO pin to be used as an output pin,
@;3:'11'-> Analog mode, which allows the GPIO pin to be used as an Analog input pin and finally,
@;2:'10'-> Alternate function mode which allow the GPIO pins to be used by peripherals such as the UART, SPI e.t.c. 
@;OTYPER
@;'0'-> output push/pull
@;'1'-> output open drain
@;OSPEEDR
@;'x0': 2MHz Low speed
@;'01':10MHz Medium speed
@;'11': 50MHz High speed
@;OPUPDR
@;'00'-> No pull-up/pull-down
@;'01'-> pull up
@;'10'-> pull down
@;'11'-> Reserved
```

How I have configured the USART:

According to the guide, I needed to set up PA9 as alternative function mode, output push pull, output low speed, and no pull-up/pull-down.

I then set up PA10 as general purpose input, floating (Though I do not need to use this at this point, I am just trying to see if I can get a character to send first.)

Next, I had to make sure the USART1 clock was enabled.

I found that the RCC_APB2ENR( RCC APB2 periperal clock enable register) is located 0x44 from RCC_base. I enabled it like so,

```
@; make sure USART1 is enabled clock
ldr r3,=RCC_BASE
ldr r2,[r3,#RCC_APB2ENR]
orr r2,#(1<<4)  @; set enable bit
str r2,[r3,#RCC_APB2ENR]
```

I then set the baud rate, and enabled the CR1 TE and RE bit.

```
@; load the baud rate (9600), baud = fclk/(16*usartdiv), fclk=16*10^6
ldr r3, =USART1_BASE
mov r2, #0x683      @; Mantissa [15:4] 0x68=0d104 Frac [3:0] 0x3
str r2, [r3, #USART_BRR]

@; enable the USARTx_CR1_UE bit
ldr r2,  [r3, #USART_CR1]
orr r2, #(1<<13)
str r2, [r3, #USART_CR1]

@; enable the USARTx_CR1_TE bit
ldr r2, [r3, #USART_CR1]
orr r2, #(1<<3)
str r2, [r3, #USART_CR1]

@; enable the USARTx_CR1_RE bit
ldr r2, [r3, #USART_CR1]
orr r2, #(1<<2)
str r2, [r3, #USART_CR1]
```

I think I have set it up correctly!

But to no avail, I am not seeing any characters show up in my serial capture program.

I just tried putting the character A in the data register but have received nothing.

```
ldr r3, =USART1_BASE
mov r2, #0x41 @; A
str r2, [r3, #USART_DR]
```

Its been a couple days now trying to debug whats wrong and I haven't found an answer. Some type of help would be appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: Note your question revolves around ST logic not ARM, this is really an ST question. And ST has more than one different uart in their product families so this is a specific chip subset of a larger family of arm based parts.  Which alternate function can vary, ST is somewhat consistent with one of the uart's pins across a number of products but there are other pins.  So you need to specify specify specifically which chip you are using.

Comment: If this were an arm assembly question then you would have a debugged pseudo code program that shows exactly what bits in what registers to set and you just want to translate that code into some other language, just like translating some text from french to english or german to russian (pseudo code to asm, or C to asm, etc).

Comment: Please dont use links, include the relevant text in the question or answer itself, links do us no good here as the stackexchange folks do not manage and maintain those sites so that the questions or answers can remain relevant.

Comment: use the documentation from the chip vendor for that part, not third party documentation for the registers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did need to enable the Moder register to alternate function mode. But what I did not do was enable the alternate function for use by USART1.

Specifically, for Pin 9 (Tx) the alternate function for USART1 can be set in the Alternate Function High Register.

More detail here: (http://web.eece.maine.edu/~zhu/book/Appendix_I_Alternate_Functions.pdf)